# Missing "+New Document" button in SharePoint form library when viewed on mobile devices (e.g. iPad)

Tags: form, library

I'm having a minor issue with SharePoint form library and wondering if any users have experienced similar issue such as this in the past can help me out.

Brief background on the issue-

I'm using SharePoint 2013 as a form database where users can upload/submit their form to the form library by clicking "New Document" on the page. My permission level is set as Site Owner by the SharePoint administrator. This is a state resource, and therefore I have no access to SharePoint Designer...but if necessary, I know someone within the department who can make the necessary adjustment(s) as needed.

In the picture below, the button disappears when viewed from iPad using Chrome (tested with Safari as well).

[image]

The "+new document" button appears when viewed from desktop.

[image]

In both instances, permission level were exactly the same using identical login.

I've Googled for a while and ransacked through Microsoft SharePoint support but to no avail. Any idea why this is happening?